# Friend function template, specialization and scope of declaration

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, friend

The following code snippet declares a friend function template and defines one specialization outside of the class:

```
class A {
    template<typename T>
    friend T f();
};

template <>
int f<int>() {
    return 0;
}
```

clang 16.0 compiles it but g++ 13.1 rejects it with

> error: 'f' is not a function template

(Both compiled with `-pedantic -std=c++2a`; g++ does compile it if the template is declared again outside of the class; clang rejects it with `int main() { f<int>(); }`.)

Which compiler is standard compliant in this case?

---

As I understand it, names that are introduced by `friend` declarations in classes are not visible during normal name lookup. Therefore I'd guess g++ is correct -- although I'm curious whether providing specializations alone (without calling `f`) is valid as per the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GCC** is correct: this is ill-formed.  This is basically [CWG2261](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2261.html), which [has been closed](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1018r18.html) as Not A Defect since [P1787](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html) clarified that ordinary lookup is employed to find the function template being instantiated (or, here, specialized) even though it is not performed for ordinary declarations like

```
void f();
```